# What MySQL driver for Node.js works on Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, node.js, npm

I would like to use MySQL with Node.js on Windows. I have tried to use [node-db-mysql](https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/), but it looks like it doesn't support Windows. Is there any other MySQL driver for Node.js that works on Windows?

Comment: Try this ans

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280784/how-to-install-node-mysql/25385003#25385003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used it, but https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql is at least pure javascript, so it should not have the same cross-platform concerns as the one you posted, which is a js wrapper around a c++ library.

Answer (score 4):

[node-mysql compatible mysql driver for node.js (node-mysql2)](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2), also works on Windows

Comment: +1 What is the main difference with this driver compared to `node-mysql`?

Comment: its a bit faster and supports prepared statements. I started it about at the same time felixge started his driver development and two drivers are completely independent on each other.

Comment: does anyone know how it's possible to "install" this ? or at least how to use it ?

Comment: install Node.js from pre-built official package ( nodejs.org ) and then do `npm install mysql-native` command

Comment: @AndreySidorov **This package is now deprecated**, replaced with [https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2)