# Node: Mysql client libraries on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, node.js

I have installed db-mysql module on node running linux, and I have not problems with it, but when I tried to do it on windows, I don't know how to do this:

$ export MYSQL_CONFIG=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

That is what the db-mysql's documentation page says to do
nodejsdb.org/db-mysql

without do that, I get on node:

Error: Unable to load shared library C:/Program files/nodejs/node_modules/db-mysql/build/Release/mysql_bindings.node

Do I have to copy any file from linux to windows pc?

Sorry my bad english, and thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

That library is a Native C++ wrapper, and has problems on Windows.

Try one of the pure js libraries. Some are covered off on this question
[What MySQL driver for Node.js works on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888078/what-mysql-driver-for-node-js-works-on-windows/8889152#8889152)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I'm going to use node-mysql instead of db-mysql, because its all made in javascript as you said and don't need that library.