# How to install node-mysql?

Tags: node.js, windows-7, node-mysql

Im in windows 7 cmd prompt,,, Im trying to instal by: `npm install node-mysql`

Im getting this:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install node-mysql
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-mysql
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-mysql
npm ERR! 404 'node-mysql' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Maybe try 'npm search mysql'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-mysql"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How to fix it? Im trying to search `npm search node-mysql`,, and I cant found it in the list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
npm install mysql
```

Node-msql (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/package.json) is named simply mysql in package.json and it exists under that name in npm registry.

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install mysql

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
giving 304

Comment: Try in different dir  than Program Files as you need administrator rights to write there

Comment: @FilipeTagliacozzi 304 is not an errorcode. Just let the installation complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm install felixge/node-mysql
```

Reference : readme.md from https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps for adding the mysql module for node js

## 1 Open your command prompt

> type npm install g-mysql for global use.

It will take time. mysql module will not get installed in the nodejs module directory. Please copy the module from the administrator directory to nodejs module folder.

To check the module is installed or not please go to node js command line and type

> require_resolve('mysql');

path to the module will be shown

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the given steps, which work for me:

1. Make a folder named `mysql` in this location:

   ```
   C:\Users\newusers\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
   ```
2. Then run the command `npm -g install mysql`

Comment: You don't need to make the folder, npm will do that for you

Answer (score -1):

You can use below commands to use mysql globally

```
npm install mysql -g
```